# On logout, clearing Activity history stack, preventing “back” button from opening last Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making an android app in which I need to logout. I have implemented the logout function but the problem is when I clicks the back button. the previous activity starts.

I've tried opening the Login activity by setting its Intent flags to FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP which seems to do as is outlined in the documentation, but does not achieve my goal of placing the Login activity at the bottom of the history stack, and preventing the user from navigating back to previously-seen logged-in activities. I also tried using android:launchMode="singleTop" for the Login activity in the manifest, but this does not accomplish my goal either (and seems to have no effect anyway).

I am using the follpowing code:

```
private OnClickListener clickLogoutListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new   AlertDialog.Builder(HomePage.this);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();


            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to logout??");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                            //intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                            finish();
                        }

                    });

            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();


            }
        };
```

Comment: I answered same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635060/how-to-clear-activity-stack-on-button-click-in-android/7635220#7635220

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY**

or define the activities in Manifest

**android:noHistory = true**

I have faced the same issues..i used these and that solved my purpose

However, i don't know your App flow..so can't be sure that this will be useful to you..but you can give a try.

Comment: shall i define this in all activities??

Comment: yes for sure..when every you call intent and you dont want to come back to that new screen once you done then pass the flag..or you are sure from the time of declaration then do it in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

When you are pressing back button an event occurs. So what you do is handle that event by onKeyDown() method like this --->

public boolean onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event){

switch(event.getAction()){
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
do something here or display some message
break;
}
return true;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

...